# How do I access an object in a decorator in RactiveJS

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am using Pikaday date picker as a decorator in RactiveJS and want to access the api of the datepicker outside of the decorator, but adding it to the return object doesn't seem to work. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

http://jsbin.com/lefiyume/1/edit?html,js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorators are designed to be reusable bridges between Ractive and external libraries - so rather than having a `startdate` decorator and an `enddate` decorator, it's better to have a single `pikaday` decorator.

The decorator function is then responsible for managing its own state and interacting with the Ractive instance. If you find yourself trying to get a reference to objects created by the decorator (i.e. the Pikaday instance) it's generally a red flag.

Here's one way you could do it: http://jsbin.com/susev/5/edit?html,js,output

In this example, we're passing a keypath to both instances of the decorator. When the `pikadayDecorator` function is called with each `<input>` node, it gets called with two arguments - the node, and the keypath. (You can have additional arguments - just comma-separate them.)

The decorator can then set up two-way binding - it *observes* the given keypath (e.g. `startdate` or `enddate`) and calls the Pikaday instance's `setDate()` method when it changes. We also use the `onSelect()` method to update Ractive's model when the selected date changes - this means that we can use the date elsewhere in our template, or even outside the Ractive instance:

```
ractive.observe('startdate', function (newDate) {
  // This may have been as a result of a `ractive.set()`, or
  // because the user interacted with the datepicker
  console.log('startdate changed to', newDate);
});
```

(Note that Pikaday will automatically convert strings like '2015-01-01' to date objects.)

There's [more information on creating decorators on the docs](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/writing-decorator-plugins).

Comment: Are these additional arguments that are passed to the decorator done by positioning rather than argument name? I want to have mindate and maxdate as params, but only need mindate on the first decorator call and only maxdate on the second call, but if these are passed by positioning rather than name this will be difficult, any ideas?

Comment: @AndrewSmith you can use object notation: `decorator='pikaday:{mindate:"2015-01-01"}'` (or even `decorator='pikaday:{mindate:{{mindate}}}'`, if it's dynamic - but then you'll need to implement an `update()` method which you return alongside `teardown()`). That way you don't need to worry about passing null values

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setDate` inside the saleEndDecorator function.

http://jsbin.com/lefiyume/7/edit